# Internet Explorer SmartScreen Filter Log File

Tags: internet-explorer, logging

does anybody know where the Internet Explorer SmartScreen Filter log files are located. I would like to use the information as part of security metrics in a security awareness program.

Hence if the user access a website which is blocked by the SmartScreen Filter then this information should be stored somewhere.

Not sure if I missed it I thought it would be in the Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the SmartScreen Filter does not log events by default (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618329.aspx). But if you use Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit 5.0 then events can be logged (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows//aa905102.aspx).